# Django: How to add ManyToMany Value in form from other Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

So i have 2 Models. 
Ingredient and recipe. 
I want to add like a plus button with a popup that will open a Modal on this page, that will let me create an Ingredient.
I don't want that the User has to create ingredients and then the Recipe.

My Models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    ingredient = models.ManyToManyField('Ingredient',)
    for_persons = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    instruction = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Rezept-Detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) 

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    UNIT_CHOICES = (
        ("ML", "Milliliter"),
        ("L", "Liter"),
        ("KG", "Kilogramm"),
        ("PCK", "Packung"),
        ("P", "Portion"),
    )
    unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=UNIT_CHOICES
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My Form:

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'ingredient', 'for_persons', 'instruction']
```

Someone know, how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a button at form action that call the Ingredient Add view like below, I would suggest to use form-helper. within FormActions you can update the  with modal for popup.
you can check form-helper using this link (https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html)

```
class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = True
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

           //some code for the fields goes here

            FormActions(
                Submit('save', _('Save')),
                HTML(
                    '<a href="link for the add ingredient" >' + _('New Ingredient ') + '</a>'),

            )
        )
    class Meta:
        model = models.Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'ingredient', 'for_persons', 'instruction']
```

Comment: Can you Explain me, where does user come from and what do you mean with code for the fields? Never worked with Crispy forms...

Comment: You can ignore the user I added if you have session. You only have to use Form helper so you can write html that let you write an anchor to open the modal.

Comment: Ok will try this :) THX